# Alleles notation in SNPPedia criteria

Tags: bioinformatics, human-genetics, snp, allele

I can understand the allele notation when is in the form rs8176719(T;T) or rs8176719(G) but recently i found this ones rs8176719(T;-) or rs8176719(-;T).

So im confused, rs8176719(T;-) is the same as rs8176719(T)? or is the location is important ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

The '-' means that that allele has a single base deletion.